# Which situations the window.opener.closed property is necessary

Tags: javascript, dom

Tried to figure out, what's the case to use the `window.opener.closed` flag? Looks like if the opener window is closed, the `window.opener` variable is set to `null`, so we can't access the `.closed` property anyway.
Is there any situation when the opener window is actually closed, but the `window.opener` is still available so we can check the `.closed` property?

Comment: I don't think we can answer _why_?

Comment: I mean does anyone know any situation when it can be acutally helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all, the behaviour of the `closed` property is heavily browser dependent. In all modern browser (Firefox, Chrome, Edge) the logic is as you've described - upon the opener Window being closed `window.opener` is nullified and the `closed` property is no longer accessible. This is however not the case for IE, where you can access the property just fine.

Secondly, the behaviour you've described happens only if you close the window by the mouse event (e.g. hovering over the 'X' icon of the browser tab and clicking it). If you close the opener Window programmatically (so by using the `close()` function), you'll see that the nullification process does not occur.

Comment: Oh, that's full answer I wanted to get. Thank you, that answers all my questions for now, just playing around didn't help much to understand this